# How to extract the frequencies associated with fft2 values in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, fft

I know that for `fft.fft`, I can use `fft.fftfreq`. But there seems to be no such thing as `fft.fftfreq2`. Can I somehow use `fft.fftfreq` to calculate the frequencies in 2 dimensions, possibly with `meshgrid`? Or is there some other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Apply `fftfreq` to each spatial vector (x and y) separately. Then create a meshgrid from those frequency vectors.

Note that you need to use `fftshift` if you want the typical representation (zero frequencies in center of spatial spectrum) to both the output and your new spatial frequencies (before using `meshgrid`).